# cannot compile a function with v$sesstat

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions

I have the following anonymous block code:

```
declare
    v_rezult  v$sesstat.value%TYPE;
begin
    select value into v_rezult from v$sesstat where rownum < 2;
    dbms_output.put_line (v_rezult);
end;
```

... which works very nice.

I want to transform it into a function, like:

```
create or replace function func_test return varchar2 is
v_rezult  v$sesstat.value%TYPE;
begin
    select value into v_rezult from v$sesstat where rownum < 2;
    return v_rezult;
end;
```

... but, when compiling, I receive the following error:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'V$SESSTAT' must be declared

Can anyone explain why so and how can I add the usage of this view into a function, please?

Thanks, Mikcutu.

Comment: Most likely you are getting access to v$sesstat though a role. However, a stored procedure cannot. It requires a direct grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the function is not being created in the SYS schema, it must be fully qualified. I would avoid making changes to SYS or SYSTEM, my recommendation is to use a different schema.
2. V$SESSTAT is a synonym for SYS.V_$SESSTAT, use SYS.V_$SESSTAT
3. Grant select on SYS.V_$SESSTAT to the owner of the function.
4. Use the appropriate return type

> -- this supposes you have an Oracle account "ADMIN"
>
> ```
> GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.v_$sesstat TO admin;
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.func_test
>     RETURN SYS.v_$sesstat.VALUE%TYPE IS
>     v_rezult   SYS.v_$sesstat.VALUE%TYPE;
> BEGIN
>     SELECT VALUE
>       INTO v_rezult
>       FROM sys.v_$sesstat
>      WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
>
>     RETURN v_rezult;
> END;
> ```

Comment: I agree but I would recommend to use synonyms instead of SYS objects